# why do rechargeable batteries fail so horribly in high drain environments?

Tags: batteries, failure

I've tried nicads and nimhs in flashlights and they always end up leaking.  I know how spikes and memory work in such batteries, but why do such high drain applications cause such catastrophic failures in these batteries while alkaline batteries perform quite well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to generalize to a battery type because any poorly made mass production battery has the risk of catastrophic failure in high drain situations just because of poor quality control.

Having said that, it is generally my experience that NiCd and NiMh perform quite superiorly in high drain situations compared to alkaline.  This is almost entirely due to their lower internal resistance compared to alkalines. The higher the internal resistance of a battery, the harder it is for the battery to provide higher currents and the hotter it will get when it provides those currents.  When the battery overheats, it can vent and warp and leak and lose capacity.

Many of the hybrid vehicles use NiMh batteries and they are used in a very high drain situation; yet the Prius for example has had very few battery failures in its 14 year history.

I have been using high quality nimh rechargeable AA and AAA in my high drain flashlights for a couple of years without a single failure. I suspect you have just had bad luck with your rechargeables? Or possibly let them drain too far or over charge them which could lead to the catastrophic failures.

Comment: I thought vehicles used lithium almost exclusively. Specifically the application I refer to is flashlights with incandescent bulbs

Comment: Is it possible that the internal resistance of alkaline batteries is essential to the function of those devices? And other cells used in their place lack the ability to sustain the current draw?

Comment: You would think that the hybrids would be using li-ions, but more are still using NiMh because of cost and stability, although more and more are moving towards li-ion

Comment: I personally only use LED flashlights, but some of them draw up to 3 amps of current, which is a lot to ask of an AA.  My understanding is that the lower internal resistance of the NiMh is what allows it to supply higher currents while: 1) staying cooler and 2)holding its charge longer/providing a higher capacity.  For example, when consumer reports tested AA alkalines, they found that all brands except the Energizer lithiun (which aren't alkalines) performed terribly in digital cameras with flash on. This is because the flash required high current, which the alkaline could not provide.

Comment: If you get the chance, Sanyo Eneloop NiMh rechargeable AA or AAA are impressive. They also hold 85%+ of their charge for one year and no memory effect. just have to make sure that you don't discharge them to lower than .9 volt/cell under load. Most of the flashlight enthusiasts seem to use them